# Optical trapping problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, laser, atomic-physics

Can we  make light slower by applying optical trapping (I mean applying laser beam  to lower the speed of light)?

Comment: You've got the wrong idea about optical trapping. Or perhaps you're referring to something I've never heard of? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of ways to create what is called [slow light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_light). You presumably mean the term as used in the same context as [Electromagnetically induced transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetically_Induced_Transparency#Slow_light_and_stopped_light).

Here you shine the light pulse you want to slow on to a cloud of atoms, and simultaneously shine a second beam on them. The resulting interactions then make for a *very* strong dependence of the cloud's absorption and dispersion on the frequency of the light. This can then slow the group velocity down to a few meters per second.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to confine light.
Keywords: optical confinement, confine light

See [Photonic crystals: New designs to confine light](http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v1/n1/full/nphys137.html), [Confining light for use in nanophotonic devices](http://phys.org/news201062078.html).

You can make light slower by making it go through a medium with higher refractive index.
For example, water has a higher refractive index than vacuum so light travels slower in water than in vacuum. ([Microscopic explanation of refraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Microscopic_explanation))

If you're wondering about what happens when two photons collide, then:

> [Even with low energy photons, there are virtual loops and photon photon interactions can happen with some probability](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/do-photons-interact-with-each-other-or-with-themselves-only#comment16062_6368)-anna v
>
> [If the energy is large enough, photons interactively create massive particles.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/6368/11833) -datenwolf