# Can two photons share spacetime?

Tags: optics, visible-light, photons, spacetime

I.e., can two photons completely overlap and propagate in the same direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do two beams of light pass through one another without interacting?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/184656/)

Comment: Related: [Do photons interact with each other or with themselves only](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6345/)

Answer (score 3):

Photons are bosons. As such they obey [Bose-Einstein statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_statistics). One of the results of this is that bosons actually like to be in the same state. This is the reason for [Bose-Einstein condenstates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate). It also the reason behind [stimulate emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimulated_emission).

So, yes indeed, two photons can completely overlap and propagate in the same direction, or in other words, exist in exactly the same state.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A 'classical' wave is a wave composed of a large number of completely coherent photons.

Comment: Not all classical fields are completely coherent.

Answer (score 1):

Photons are point particles in the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg) of particle physics  and as such they are described by a wave function which is a solution of a [quantized Maxwell's equation](http://cds.cern.ch/record/944002/files/0604169.pdf).

Wave functions  can be superimposed in space time, with no problem. It is the complex conjugate squared of the wave function which gives the probability of finding a photon at an (x,y,z,t). (Superposition gives the diffraction patterns observed in [laser beams](http://www.conspiracyoflight.com/LaserInterference/LaserInterference.html)  , and it is not an interaction).

If there is a possible interaction vertex, then some of the photons would interact and change direction, but the probability is very very small as there are four electromagnetic vertices in the [feynman diagram.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics)