# Does the size of a photon change depending on the energy level/wavelength of the light?

Tags: photons

Basically the title. And if so, is there a proportional relationship?

Comment: A photon has no size.

Answer (score -2):

The amplitude of the wave components change,  but  the photon itself has no size.

Comment: I suspect you're getting downvotes because your statement is unsupported. If you look at the answers to [the question I linked](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206772/what-is-size-of-photon) you'll see they go into some detail in explaining why a photon has no size. It's this sort of effort that we expect of answers here.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive comment. I will keep this in mind going forward.